# Google sign-in stopped working after I replaced the original google-services.json with one pertaining to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, google-play-services

Here is my code for google sign-in

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround. When we integrate firebase messaging, we have to add FirebaseAuth for google sign-in.